# correcting z-index order for background image with dark filter as content and flowbite modal from tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css, background-image, z-index, flowbite

So let's me example you first , i'm creating index page that has css with some dark-background filter in id-content::before and it has z-index: -1 and actual id-content with background-image has z-index :1 and it's working as expected but when i using with flowbite modal that have default value of z-index : 40 and modal body of z-50 it orders z-50 first before z-40 so i'm not sure right now what to do , if i delete z-index : 1 part in id-content the modal work perfectly fine.

here s' code so far

```css
#content.custom-bg {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #content.custom-bg::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
      z-index: -1;
      background-blend-mode: multiply;
    }
    #content {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      min-height: 100vh;
      background-image:'example.png';
    }
```

```html
<section id="app">
  <div id="content" class="p-4 custom-bg">
    <div class="sm-max:mt-21 mt-6">
    @yield('content') <- there s' modal inside this. [just basiclly laravel]
    </div>
</section>
```

flowbite default css of modal background i know so far :

'bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 dark:bg-opacity-80 fixed inset-0 z-40',

and modal body

'fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden w-full p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-modal md:h-full'

so from what i know the current order of z-index is : -1 (from ::before)-> 1 (id-content)-> 40(flowbite-modal-bg) -> 50(flowbite-modal-body)
but looks like i got : -1 -> 1 -> 40 -> 1 or -1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 40 [i'm not pretty sure rn.]

I just don't want modal and background images to be conflict with each other.

sry for my bad english

Comment: i've solve it guys 

i just go torch grass and new solution just install into my head

Comment: Can you share the solution as an answer? It may also help those who have similar problem like you in the future.

Comment: yep, I've put the down below as Answer , it turn out just it was simple, i need to go learn about box models again XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved it by just separate modal-content out of the box in id-content like this below

```
<section id="app">
<div id="content" class="sm:ml-16 lg:ml-64 p-4">
<div class="sm-max:mt-21 mt-6">
    @yield('content') <- Page Content
</div>
</div>
<div id="modal-content">
    @yield('modal-content') <- Modal Content
</div>
</section>
```